# detect what columns to select depending on a column value of the same table

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008

I am trying to build a query which returns different columns of the table depending on a column of the same table. Say, a column represents a type of item.

This is my temporary solution, in which I just combine the results of multiple queries.

As you can see, I use "AS" keyword to rename the default column name.

```
SELECT [custom].[dbo].[records].[id] AS "ID",[type_name] AS "Тип записи", [domain_name] AS "Значение", [custom].[dbo].[records].[record_type_id] FROM [custom].[dbo].[records] INNER JOIN [custom].[dbo].[record_type] ON [custom].[dbo].[records].record_type_id = [custom].[dbo].[record_type].id WHERE [custom].[dbo].[records].record_type_id = 1
union all
SELECT [custom].[dbo].[records].[id] AS "ID",[type_name] AS "Тип записи", CAST([ip_address] AS nvarchar(15)) AS "Значение", [custom].[dbo].[records].[record_type_id] FROM [custom].[dbo].[records] INNER JOIN [custom].[dbo].[record_type] ON [custom].[dbo].[records].record_type_id = [custom].[dbo].[record_type].id WHERE [custom].[dbo].[records].record_type_id = 2
union all
SELECT [custom].[dbo].[records].[id] AS "ID",[type_name] AS "Тип записи", [domain_name] AS "Значение", [custom].[dbo].[records].[record_type_id] FROM [custom].[dbo].[records] INNER JOIN [custom].[dbo].[record_type] ON [custom].[dbo].[records].record_type_id = [custom].[dbo].[record_type].id WHERE [custom].[dbo].[records].record_type_id = 3
union all
SELECT [custom].[dbo].[records].[id] AS "ID",[type_name] AS "Тип записи", [mail_domain]  AS "Значение", [custom].[dbo].[records].[record_type_id] FROM [custom].[dbo].[records] INNER JOIN [custom].[dbo].[record_type] ON [custom].[dbo].[records].record_type_id = [custom].[dbo].[record_type].id WHERE [custom].[dbo].[records].record_type_id = 4
union all
SELECT [custom].[dbo].[records].[id] AS "ID",[type_name] AS "Тип записи", CAST([ip_address] AS nvarchar(15)) AS "Значение", [custom].[dbo].[records].[record_type_id] FROM [custom].[dbo].[records] INNER JOIN [custom].[dbo].[record_type] ON [custom].[dbo].[records].record_type_id = [custom].[dbo].[record_type].id WHERE [custom].[dbo].[records].record_type_id = 5
union all
SELECT [custom].[dbo].[records].[id] AS "ID",[type_name] AS "Тип записи", [domain_name] AS "Значение", [custom].[dbo].[records].[record_type_id] FROM [custom].[dbo].[records] INNER JOIN [custom].[dbo].[record_type] ON [custom].[dbo].[records].record_type_id = [custom].[dbo].[record_type].id WHERE [custom].[dbo].[records].record_type_id = 6
union all
SELECT [custom].[dbo].[records].[id] AS "ID",[type_name] AS "Тип записи", [service_name] AS "Значение", [custom].[dbo].[records].[record_type_id] FROM [custom].[dbo].[records] INNER JOIN [custom].[dbo].[record_type] ON [custom].[dbo].[records].record_type_id = [custom].[dbo].[record_type].id WHERE [custom].[dbo].[records].record_type_id = 7
```

Comment: It's columns, not fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with CASE operator the query will be shorter

```
SELECT 
[custom].[dbo].[records].[id] AS "ID",
[type_name] AS "Тип записи", 

case [custom].[dbo].[records].record_type_id 
when 1 then [domain_name] 
when 2 then ...
when 7 then [service_name]
end AS "Значение", 

[custom].[dbo].[records].[record_type_id] 
FROM [custom].[dbo].[records] 
INNER JOIN [custom].[dbo].[record_type]
ON [custom].[dbo].[records].record_type_id = [custom].[dbo].[record_type].id 
WHERE [custom].[dbo].[records].record_type_id in (1, 2... 7)
```